# Get the result set based on column's first character in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have following table structure.

Table : **Vehicle**

```
+--------+--------+-------+----------+
| Diesel | Petrol |  LPG  | Hybrid   |
+--------+--------+-------+----------+
| yes    | no     |   no  |  no      |
| no     | yes    |   no  |  no      |
| no     | no     |   yes |  no      |
| no     | no     |   no  |  yes     |  
+--------+--------+-------+----------+
```

I want to retrieve records set based column's first character from stored procedure parameter. So far I have tried below query.

My @FuelType Parameter value looks like 'D,P,L'.

```
 Select * from Vehicle 
 Where (Diesel = Case When CharIndex('D', @FuelType) > 0 Then 'yes' 
                 Else 'no' End) 
 Or (Petrol = Case When CharIndex('P', @FuelType) > 0 Then 'yes' 
              Else 'no' End) 
 Or (LPG = Case When CharIndex('L', @FuelType) > 0 Then 'yes' 
              Else 'no' End) 
 Or (Hybrid = Case When CharIndex('H', @FuelType) > 0 Then 'yes' 
              Else 'no' End)
```

Is there any possibility available to optimize the above query?

Comment: What isn't working about it?

Comment: @roryap  It is working fine. Is there any possibility to optimize above query?

Comment: Optimize how?  Is it not running fast enough?  Seems to me if it's working fine then why mess with it.  I can't think of any way to do what you're doing other than with a case when, but I'm far from a SQL guru.

Comment: Don't think you have many other options apart from what you are doing. You can consider using just one column for the fuel type and then splitting the string and building a temporary table with the different individual values and inner-join to that

Comment: You can calculate the `charindex` value before hand and then in `where` clause do something like `((@dcharindex > 0 AND Diesel = 'yes') OR  Diesel = 'no')`. Because calling the function in where clause hampers the performance. You should read about how to make query `Seragable`.

Comment: I suggest you to optimize the structure itself cause the way it is, it's not normalized...fuel types need to be in a separate table...not columns in your vehicle table...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the query, but there's certainly an opportunity to better normalize the schema design. You have a many-to-many relationship between vehicles and fuel types. You should resolve this with a junction table.

[image]

Your query can then become something like:

```
SELECT v.*
    FROM Vehicle v
        INNER JOIN Vehicle_FuelType_Xref vftx
            ON v.VehicleID = vftx.VehicleID
        INNER JOIN Fuel_Type ft
            ON vftx.FuelTypeID = ft.FuelTypeID
    WHERE ft.FuelType IN ('Diesel', 'Petrol', 'LPG');
```

Comment: I don't think it's a many-to-many relationship but a one-to-many...vehicle can have only one fuel type...but so like you suggest, fuel type have to be in a separate table and an FK added to the vehicle table...

Comment: @FabienTheSolution Possibly. His sample data seems to suggest that. But think of a real world case where some car engines can run on regular gasoline or an E85 blend.